# Git push failed updating remote server info

Tags: git

When I try to push the new branch in the remote origin I get the following error. I am able to push the commits on the existing branches and there is no problem on existing branches.

```
git push -u origin master1
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/tags/
  refs/heads/
updating 'refs/heads/master1'
  from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  to   346c3424fd1ab8988581672347f9f3c81d4e6919
    sending 23276 objects
PUT 6566108bbc5a91c64ab4cc084262fec5da9def36 failed, aborting (52/100)
Updating remote server info
fatal: git-http-push failed
To http://git.example.org/repoTab.git
 ! [remote rejected] master1 -> master1
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://git.exampple.org/repoTab.git'
```

There is also following error comes up in apache error log during this problem, which is as follows:

```
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:23.665942 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 11594 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:24.667428 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29643 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:25.668503 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29680 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:26.669711 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29679 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
0 molecules converted
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:27.671108 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29735 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:28.672170 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29765 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:30.674527 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29766 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:31.675800 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29821 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:32.677236 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29858 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:34.679307 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29886 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:35.680588 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29887 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Thu Sep 17 17:02:36.682016 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29943 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
1 molecule converted
[Thu Sep 17 17:03:02.708032 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29971 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x7fe7294fe4f0, Perl interpreter: 0x7fe72943ac10 during global destruction.
Scalars leaked: 1
[Thu Sep 17 17:03:05.711402 2015] [core:notice] [pid 29392:tid 140630788532096] AH00052: child pid 29972 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

gdb gives the following information:

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/sbin/apache2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/sbin/apache2...done.
done.
Attaching to program: /usr/sbin/apache2, process 28557
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libaprutil-1.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapr-1.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.19.so...done.
done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_apreq2.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_apreq2.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapreq2.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapreq2.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_basic.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_core.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_core.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_core.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authn_file.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_core.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_host.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_user.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_autoindex.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_cgid.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_fs.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_fs.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_fs.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dir.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dnssd.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dnssd.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-common.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavahi-client.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_env.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_filter.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_filter.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_filter.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mime.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_negotiation.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_perl.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.20...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.20
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_setenvif.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_userdir.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil-2.19.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
0x00007f1a390a8293 in __select_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory
```

Comment: have you tried creating an "empty" branch and then pushing it? Could it be a "create branch not allowed" permission problem?

Comment: tried with empty branch it says: error: failed to push some refs to http://git.exampple.org/repoTab.git

Comment: There is also following error comes up in apache error log during this problem, which is as follows:

Comment: A backtrace (`bt` in `gdb`) could help here.